# Why Hinduism SE doesn't have "not Constructive" and "not a real question" options for closing questions?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, close-reasons

Many Stack exchange sites have **"not constructive"** and **"not a real question"** options to close a question if question is not constructive or real. There are few questions on this site which are very trivial. For example,

[What is the difference of “Sri”, “Shri”, “Shree”, “Sree”](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12340/3500)

[Are there any temples of Hindu Gods in America?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11160/3500)

These questions belong to either of these categories. First question is closed as off-topic, but in reality this question is about Hinduism but as question is very trivial it was closed but closed as off-topic. Similarly, Wikipedia answers 2nd question. So, this question is clearly not a real question or not constructive. We can define scope of these options or at least one of the above options will be useful to effective closing.

Why these options are not available here? How about introducing them now for effective closing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" were used in earlier (olden) days on StackExchange Network. Now, they are obsolete.

Actually

- Not Constructive and
- Not a Real Question

**are eliminated and replaced with the following more effective option:**

- unclear what you’re asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based

Visit the Meta.SE post [Help us make “Not Constructive” and “Not a Real Question” closures more effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732/260388) for information about it.